# how do i unit testing this method in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, testing, webforms, mvp

i'm creating a shopping website that will sell computer parts using MVP and asp.net. i'm trying to unit test a model in Bussiness layer which will insert some values into db using Entity model.

```
public class CategoryModelRepsitory : IModelRepository
{
    public void Insert(string catName, long catParent)
    {
        EntityContext con = new EntityContext();
        Category cat = new Category();
        cat.Name = catName;
        cat.Parent = catParent;
        con.Category.AddObject(cat);
        con.SaveChanges();
    }
    //other methods like update and delete
}
```

so how do i unit test this and verify the expectations using built-in visual studio test classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Unity ( http://unity.codeplex.com/ ) or NInject ( http://www.ninject.org/ ) + Moq ( http://code.google.com/p/moq/ ) to allow your architecture to be easily tested, for example:

```
[Dependency]    
IDataContext Context {get; set;}
```

After that you'll be able to mock the IDataContext in your tests and check if some methods with needed parameters were called

p.s.
By the way I'm not sure that especially this will be even compilable, but approach should be like that.

In addition I'd recommend you to write some abstract IRepository class and access database using it

This will also add more testability to your project.
(it's very bad approach to create the DataContexts inside the method, it should be one for one client or thread + should be calcualted using DI + IoC principles)

Comment: what is IDataContext? is it the EntityContext in my example? if it is where would i define the dependancy? can't i do it by vs.net only?

Comment: Check this one:
http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/agile-entity-framework-4-repository-part-2-the-repository/

Comment: i have saved the series but it doesn't refer to DI or IoC explicity anywhere so how do i recognize them in code samples of the series?

Comment: You BaseRepository should have public property IDataContext which will be resolved by Unity or NInject.

You should use only this property to access Database.

This will allow you to test your code.

Comment: ok so this public property is the Dependancy and the IDataContext is the Ioc? please correct it if i'm wrong...